# Three.js Moving the camera along a path after click event

Tags: javascript, animation, camera, three.js

For the past ... many hours, I've tried, searched and read on how to get a camera moving along a path in Three.js. I just can't seem to find it, or I've become saturated and can't see an answer, even if it bit me in the face.

What I want isn't that hard. I have several icon-like things in a 3D space, that I want to be able to click on. I've got the THREEx extension for it, so that part is fine. Now the part where the camera moves smoothly along a predetermined path, together with its lookAt Y-axis, so that it faces the next 'icon'.

My first approach was to make a path using a Bezier curve and find out how to make one of those in a spiral-shape going slightly upwards, then finding out how to animate the camera along that path after the click event. I'm still stuck - hard - at trying to find out how to make a simple path that curves upwards, let alone the daunting part after.

Am I on the right track at all? If so, how do I make a path like that? Or should I just make a regular Bezier curve and rotate and edit that until it fits my needs? And lastly, how dow I make the camera follow the path in a (short) animated, smooth motion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this three.js example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://cubic.org/docs/hermite.htm

It explains curve calculation, including variations you'll want to be aware. For example, a bezier curve is not a good curve for animation because it does not drop points equal distant front one another, leading to an unintended speed changes with the camera.

At the link, the discussion starts with a quit math explainer, provides pseudo code, and then shows how to derive several popular types of curves with variations of the same initial math. This continues to TCB: Tension, Continuity, & Bias Curves, which give you the nice type of controls you'll want on your camera.